# Upgrade Wheezy -> Jessie, Gitlab index page not working

Tags: apache-2.4, gitlab, debian-jessie

I installed gitlab on my Debian Wheezy server a few days ago and I managed to get it working with:

- Apache
- Relative URL (/gitlab)
- HTTPS

I installed it from source following [the official installation guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md).

I just upgraded to Debian Jessie and after some changes to my apache conf files, I managed to get gitlab almost working...

I can go to `domain.com/gitlab`: I get redirected `domain.com/gitlab/users/sign_in`.

But when I am logged in, I cannot access `domain.com/gitlab`! I can access everything (at least I think), such as:

```
/gitlab/dashboard/
/gitlab/<username>/<project-name>
/gitlab/admin
```

And so on... But not `domain.com/gitlab`...

My `log/production.log` when I try to access `/gitlab`:

```
Started GET "/gitlab/index.html" for 140.93.2.243 at 2016-01-26 08:15:56 +0100
Processing by NamespacesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"index.html"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 28ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
```

What I tried:

```
# Checking the installation: Everything looked ok.
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production

# Reinstalling gitlab-shell (and updating the config for https)
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:shell:install 
    REDIS_URL=unix:/var/run/redis/redis.sock RAILS_ENV=production

# (Re)-setting up my DB
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production

# (Re)-compiling assets
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Feel free to ask for more details, I don't know what may or may not be relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by installing the passenger module:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger
```

And in my conf file, enabling the following two lines:

```
RailsEnv production
PassengerAppRoot /home/git/gitlab
```

---

Details:

In Apache 2.2 I used the following:

```
Alias /gitlab "/home/git/gitlab/public/"
<Directory "/home/git/gitlab/public">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all

#    RailsEnv production
#    SetEnv RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT "/gitlab"
#    PassengerAppRoot /home/git/gitlab

    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
    ProxyPassReverse http://YOUR_SERVER_FQDN/

    # Redirect directives from original gitlab-ssl-apache22.conf
</Directory>
```

I am not even sure that the `proxy` directives were doing something but it was working.

In Apache 2.4, Proxy directives are not allowed in `Directory`, so I use the following:

```
Alias /gitlab "/home/git/gitlab/public/"
<Directory "/home/git/gitlab/public">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Options -MultiViews
    Require all granted

    RailsEnv production
    PassengerAppRoot /home/git/gitlab

    # Same Redirect directives
</Directory>
```